# Can access a server but cannot map it to a drive

Tags: mappeddrive

I had to disconnect from a mapped shared drive at work. Now, it seems I cannot re-map it. However, if I type in the address on Windows Explorer, I can certainly browse to it and access files within it. Note that this does NOT happen with any other mapped drives, just this one.

Running the `net use` command gives me error 67

How can I successfully re-map this drive?

The computers on the domain are all Windows10, while the domain manager is 2008 Windows Server. I am unsure about the details of the shared drive itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was about access restrictions. I could indeed connect to \Server on windows explorer, but within it, I was able to access only some folders (ie \Server\folderA but not \Server\folderB). Therefore, I had to map to \Server\folderA and not the main \Server path